# What is the range of this complex function: $f(z) = 2x^2+(1-x^2)(1+i)$ defined on $|z|\leq1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

These range problems, I just don't get it.

I tried to get this into a form where I could use the fact that $0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$, but I'm just not sure how to get it to that point.  Any ${hints}$ would very welcome! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let $z = re^{i\theta} = r \cos \theta + i r \sin \theta$.  Fix $r \in [0,1]$, and look at the parametric curve defined by $f(re^{i\theta})$.  What is this curve?  Now, as a function of $r$, what happens to the family of curves?  Now what is the region formed by the set $$\{f(z) \in \mathbb C : |z| \le 1\}?$$

---

For example:  $$\begin{align*} f(re^{i\theta}) &= 2(re^{i\theta})^2 + (1-(re^{i\theta})^2)(1+i) \\ &= (1-i)r^2 e^{2i\theta} + (1+i) \\ &= r^2(1-i)(\cos 2\theta + i \sin 2\theta) + (1+i) \\ &= \left(r^2 (\cos 2\theta + \sin 2\theta) + 1\right) + \left( r^2(\sin 2\theta - \cos 2\theta) + 1 \right) i. \end{align*}$$

What is the real component?  What is the imaginary component?  If $r$ is fixed, then what parametric curve do the real and imaginary components describe in the complex plane?

Comment: But I'm given $f(z)$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, so I'm unsure how to get it to the point where I could even substitute in $z=re^{i\theta}$... That's pretty much the  biggest problem I'm facing right now.

Comment: I interpreted your question to mean $f(z) = 2z^2 + (1-z^2)(1+i)$.  If what you really mean is $f(z) = 2\Re(z)^2 + (1-\Re(z)^2)(1+i),$ that is an entirely different matter, one that merely requires us to assume that the domain is $\Re(z) \in [-1,1]$.

Comment: Then, given that I wrote my question properly, would the range be $0\leq x^2\leq1$?